# enumerate with custom alphabet for items

Tags: macros, enumerate, labels, enumitem

I'm looking for a way to use `enumerate` from package `enumitem` with a custom alphabet. For starting, I just wanted to use letters instead of numbers, so I renewed the command that outputs `item` labels. I did:

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\alph{enumi}}
```

before `\begin{enumerate}`. But soon after I realised that I need letters č, š and ž, and that my alphabet has 25 characters, so I decided to create a command that would output a letter corresponding to a number. I did:

```
\newcommand*{\xslalph}[1]{%
    \ifcase#1\or a\or b\or c\or \v{c}\or d\or e\or f\or g\or h\or i%
    \or j\or k\or l\or m\or n\or o\or p\or r\or s\or \v{s}%
    \or t\or u\or v\or z\or \v{z}%
    \else\@ctrerr\fi
}
```

That would work if I wanted to get a character from this alphabet in the middle of text, for example in a sentence, I'd write `\xslalph{3}` and I'd get "c". But this didn't work in the above situation. Both `\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\xslalph{enumi}}`, `\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\xslalph{\value{enumi}}}` and `\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\xslalph{\theenumi}}` would output "Missing number, treated as zero. \item" in the error log and no text would appear as the label of the item.

What would be the appropriate way to "pass" some number into my `\xslalph` command from the enumi counter? I'm sorry for misunderstanding, but I come from the world of C-like languages and am not used to LaTeX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, welcome to TeX.SX!

`enumitem` allows to do use other numbering systems in `enumerate` environments with the `\AddEnumerateCounter` command. It is described in section 8.1 of the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).

Here's an implementation of the counter using your `\xslalph` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xslalph}[1]{\expandafter\@xslalph\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\@xslalph}[1]{%
    \ifcase#1\or a\or b\or c\or \v{c}\or d\or e\or f\or g\or h\or i%
    \or j\or k\or l\or m\or n\or o\or p\or r\or s\or \v{s}%
    \or t\or u\or v\or z\or \v{z}%
    \else\@ctrerr\fi%
}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\xslalph}{\@xslalph}{m}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\xslalph*)]
    \item test
    \item test
    \item test
    \item test
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, can confirm this works as expected with latest TeX and enumitem on TeXStudio.

Comment: +and I am very sorry for not RTFDing and letting myself be spoon-fed. :D

Comment: I want to do something similar with labels from Georgian language. But I can not figure out how to do it. What should I use instead of \xslalf and \@xslalph from above?

Comment: @EvgenyKuznetsov It should work with these commands if you change the alphabet used in the definition of ``\@xslalph``. So you should replace ``a``,``b``,``c``,``\vc{c}``, etc. with the letters of the alphabet that you want to use, placed in correct order.

Comment: I did what you suggest but do not why but it did not work. Then I tried example from package documentation and it worked fine. Thank you for attention.