# AddEnumerateCounter with beamer's custom enumerate

Tags: beamer, labels, enumitem

I am using the `enumitem` package in order to customise enumeration by setting a custom set of characters for `enumerate` `item` `label`s.

When I normally make article-type documents, I use the following code.

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xslalph}[1]{\expandafter\@xslalph\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\@xslalph}[1]{%
    \ifcase#1\or a\or b\or c\or \v{c}\or d\or e\or f\or g\or h\or i%
    \or j\or k\or l\or m\or n\or o\or p\or r\or s\or \v{s}%
    \or t\or u\or v\or z\or \v{z}%
    \else\@ctrerr\fi%
}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\xslalph}{\@xslalph}{m}
\makeatother
```

(I got this code from my previous question --- [enumerate with custom alphabet for items](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/538082))

I am now working on a `beamer` presentation. `beamer` uses a special internal script for handling enumeration that is incompatible with `enumitem`, so `enumitem` cannot be `use`d in a `beamer` `documentclass`.

How do I use `AddEnumerateCounter` in beamer slides? I want to have `item`s alphabetically `label`ed with Slovenian letters (abcčdefghijklmnoprsštuvzž).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION n°1**

As `beamer` uses the `enumerate` package and according to the documentation of this package, you can provide customized counter styles. See section 2 of the documentation about `\@enhook`.

`pgffor` and `muticol` are here just for the sake of the example.

This is if you only want such a numbering locally.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\makeatletter
% Same definition of \xsalph than what you provided
\newcommand{\xslalph}[1]{\expandafter\@xslalph\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\@xslalph}[1]{%
    \ifcase#1\or a\or b\or c\or \v{c}\or d\or e\or f\or g\or h\or i%
    \or j\or k\or l\or m\or n\or o\or p\or r\or s\or \v{s}%
    \or t\or u\or v\or z\or \v{z}%
    \else\@ctrerr\fi%
}
% Extention of enumerate package according to documentation section 2. about "\@enhook"
% Makes * trigger \xslalph enumeration style
\providecommand\@enhook{}
\g@addto@macro\@enhook{%
\ifx *\@entemp\def\@tempa{\@enLabel\xslalph}%
\fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[*]
    \foreach \nitem in {1,...,25}{
\item \nitem.
    }
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**SOLUTION n°2**

You can modify the `enumerate item` style globally with

```
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{\xslalph{enumi}.}
```

the output is the same but does not require an option to the `enumerate` environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\makeatletter
% Same definition of \xsalph than what you provided
\newcommand{\xslalph}[1]{\expandafter\@xslalph\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\@xslalph}[1]{%
    \ifcase#1\or a\or b\or c\or \v{c}\or d\or e\or f\or g\or h\or i%
    \or j\or k\or l\or m\or n\or o\or p\or r\or s\or \v{s}%
    \or t\or u\or v\or z\or \v{z}%
    \else\@ctrerr\fi%
}
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{\xslalph{enumi}.}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
    \foreach \nitem in {1,...,25}{
    \item \nitem.
    }
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The first solution was what I am using now, thanks!